# django atomic transactions with forign key model

Tags: django-models, transactions, atomic, rollback

models.py

```
class Model1(models.Model):
        title=models.Charfield(max_length=20,defulte='some string')


 class Model2(models.Model):
        key=models.Forignkey(Model1,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**script.py**

```
    @atomic.transaction
    def my_fuc():
        obj1=Model1.objects.create(title='string for obj 1')
        obj2=Model2.objects.create(key_id=obj1.id)
```

now i need  both obj1 and obj2 created with roleback if one of them failed.
i got this error message:
**obj1 matching query does not exist.**

any idea to run this function with rollback in case of one object commit faild ?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these resources
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.get_rollback

try it as a context manager

```
with transaction.atomic():
   obj1=Model1.objects.create(title='string for obj 1')
   obj2=Model2.objects.create(key=obj1)

return obj2 # any one as you need
```